# Centralizando utilizando o position absolute

Tags: css, css3

Não estou entendo o seguinte código:

```
div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

[**Exemplo online**](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/t6ujbts4/1/)

Eu sei que definir top: 0 e bottom: 0 e setar uma largura o elemento vai esticar ocupando height: 100% do elemento pai(body), o mesmo com left: 0 e right: 0 (me corrijam se eu estiver errado).
**Mas oque eu não entendo é o margin: auto**, alguém pode me explicar como ele vai centralizar o elemento no centro ?

Answer (score 4):

Para centralizar algo no centro da pagina existe várias técnicas.

Explicando o `margin` sua função como observado é definir uma margem para algum elemento, e quando seu valor esta `auto` quer dizer que o navegador irá definir a margem automaticamente, segue exemplo:

```css
.quadrado{
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quadrado"></div>
```

Observe que estou utilizando `margin: 0 auto` o zero representa o `margin-top` e o `margin-bottom`, e o valor `auto` representa o `margin-left` e o `margin-right` resumindo é uma abreviação.

No meu exemplo as margens da direita e esquerdas estão automáticas e com isso o navegador defini automaticamente seu posicionamento, e quando o elemento é um bloco com largura definida ele centraliza horizontalmente.

Para alinhar horizontalmente e verticalmente eu utilizaria esta técnica:

```css
body, .container, html{
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quadrado{
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="quadrado"></div>
 </div>
```

Obs. Quando você defini `margin: auto` você esta atribuindo uma margin automática para `top right bottom left`

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

Este trecho de código deve resolver o seu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, eu estava com essa dúvida também e coloquei na div com `absolute` o `left` e o `right` com `-50%`

```
div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -50%;
    right: -50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

No meu caso, não coloquei o `bottom: 0;`, mas pode ser que no seu caso seja necessário.

Comment: Com esse código a div nem aparece na tela, vc testou isso onde? https://jsfiddle.net/twhxf5k4/ não funciona